# Why is my solution to $-xy(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y))+(x-y^2)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y))=0$ incorrect?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve this PDE: $$-xy(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y))+(x-y^2)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y))=0$$

A condition is given in the form of: $f(x,0)=-x$

A suggestion with the following substitution is given, where $a$ is a "suitable" constant:

$$\begin{Bmatrix} u(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{a}{x}\\v(x,y)= \frac{y}{x} \end{Bmatrix}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(u(x,y),v(x,y))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=f_{u}^{'}(-\frac{ax+2y^2}{x^3})+f_{v}^{'}(\frac{y}{x^2}) \\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(u(x,y),v(x,y))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=f_{u}^{'}(-\frac{y}{x^2})+f_{v}^{'}(\frac{1}{x})$$

So now we can substitue:

$$-xy(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y))+(x-y^2)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y))=0\\ f_{u}^{'}\ \frac{(2+a)y}{x}+ f_{v}^{'} =0$$

If we let $a=-2$ we arrive at:

$$f_{v}^{'} =0 \\ f(u,v)= g(u)$$
From the condition we know: $-u=f(u,0)=g(u)$
So we should arrive at: $$f(x,y)=-\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}$$
Nevertheless this incorrect, but I cannot see where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-xy(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y))+(x-y^2)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y))=0$$
In fact a characteristic equation is :
$$-\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}=c$$
Thus the general solution is :
$$f(x,y)=\Phi\left(-\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}\right)$$
where $\Phi(X)$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the specified condition).

Condition : $f(x,0)=-x$
$$f(x,0)=\Phi\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)=-x$$
Let $X=\frac{2}{x} \quad\implies\quad x=\frac{2}{X}$
$$\Phi(X)=-\frac{2}{X}$$
Now the function $\Phi(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=-\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}$
$$f(x,y)=-\frac{2}{X}=-\frac{2}{-\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}}$$
$$f(x,y)=\frac{2x^2}{y^2-2x}$$